# Trend and Seasonality from time series

Tags: time-series, trend, autoregressive-models

how can we extract trend, seasonality from a time series in a way SARIMAX does internally.

I need to use the same to understand how much importance (feature importance) trend, seasonality, AR component, MA component and exogenous variables are to the forecast.

Comment: Present your code that you have already tried to reach a solution?

Comment: stepwise_fit_SARIMAX = auto_arima(ts_df1, start_p=1, start_q=1, max_p=6, max_q=6, 
                          start_P=1, start_Q=1, max_P=6, max_Q=6,
                          m=12 ,# mean monthly data
                          seasonal=True,
                          d=1, D=1, trace=False,
                          error_action='ignore',  # don't want to know if an order does not work
                          suppress_warnings=True,  # don't want convergence warnings
                          stepwise=True)  # set to stepwise

Comment: p,d,q = get_pdq_parameters(stepwise_fit_SARIMAX.summary())
P,D,Q,s = get_PDQs_parameters(stepwise_fit_SARIMAX.summary())

Comment: With the above 2 code snippets i am able to get the optimum p,q,d,P, D, Q ,s parameters which would be used by SARIMAX algorithm to fit on the data. Now i am not sure how to extract Trend, Seasonality, Autoregressive, Moving Average, components which i can use along with the exogenous variable to show how much importance (feature importance) each of the component is bearing on the forecast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way -

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

#decomposition
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(x = df.y, model = 'multiplicative') 
decomposition.plot()

# df is the dataframe of y is the name of column having values of which you want 
to see trends and seasonality.
# model value can be additive or multiplicative.
```